# How to create a drop down pipeline variable in codefresh (CI/CD)

Tags: cicd, argoproj, codefresh

I want to use multiple values for a single pipeline variable in codefresh.

For example let say the variable name is `ENVIRONMENT` and it's values can be `env1, env2, env3 ...`

For such variable creating a dropdown list would immensely helpful

I went through codefresh official doc - https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/codefresh-yaml/variables/ but no luck

Is there any reference for how to create a dropdown type pipeline variable ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this (yet).  It's one of the things majorly lacking in Codefresh from usability point of view.